# Enter key works manually but not when sent via paramiko invoke_shell.sendall

Tags: python, shell, paramiko, cisco, ucs

I am looking for a way to login via SSH to a Cisco UCS server and execute few commands.

I am able to login and execute several commands and get the output. But the one command that requires <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> key doesn't seem to work.

If I try the same via terminal manually, it works. Looks like <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is not being executed on the server regardless of using `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`.

```
ssh = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
ucs = ssh.invoke_shell()
ucs.sendall('scope chassis\r\n')
time.sleep(2)
ucs.sendall('power on\r\n')
time.sleep(2)
ucs.sendall("y\r\n")
time.sleep(10)
ucs.sendall('show\r\n')
time.sleep(10)
s = ucs.recv(4096)
with open("Output.txt", "ab") as text_file:
    text_file.write(s)
with open("temp2", "wb") as text_file:
    text_file.write(s)
ssh.close()
```

```
hostname# scope chassis
hostname /chassis #
hostname /chassis # power on
This operation will change the server's power state.
Do you want to continue?[y|N]y

hostname /chassis #
hostname /chassis # show
Power Serial Number Product Name  PID           UUID
----- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------------------------------
off   xxxxxxxxxxx   UCS C240 M3S  UCSC-C240-M3S xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be looking at this command:

```py
ucs.sendall('power on\r\n')
```

It is  possible that because you are using both `\r` and `\n` that the console is interpreting the `\r` to accept the `power on` command and the `\n` to immediately cancel it. So before you get the chance to input <kbd>Y</kbd>, the command has already been cancelled by the preceding `\n`.

Comment: Thank You so much for your explanation! It worked. I will play around \r and see if \n is necessary at all.